# Nagios - check_disk - custom notification

Tags: nagios

I would like to reconfigure Nagios e-mail notification to send me information about largest files on a disk.

This is oneliner which shows me largest 20 files:

```
find / -type f -ls | sort -k 7 -r -n | head -20 |grep -v lastlog | awk '{ sum=$7 ; hum[1024**3]="Gb";hum[1024**2]="Mb";hum[1024]="Kb"; for (x=1024**3; x>=1024; x/=1024){ if (sum>=x) { printf "%.2f %s" " " $11 "\n",sum/x,hum[x];break;} }}'
```

I'd like Nagios to trigger this command on check_disk alert and to attach results in Nagios notification.

Could that be possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use [`check_nrpe`](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/nrpe/NRPE.pdf) for this and add it as a separate check and give it the one liner as the remote command to be executed. You can't alter `check_disk` unless you edit the source code and recompile it.

The max output for [`chech_nrpe`](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/nrpe/NRPE.pdf) is 1024 chars, so you might need to cut it down a bit.